# Where do these inputs get their "imaginary" properties from?

Tags: html, css

The other basic elements I tested do not have this.  This is a test fiddle I created to show the issue:

The most obvious one is the width of 145px.  This is not in the agent-style sheet or in the user styles.

It seems to come from nowhere.

https://jsfiddle.net/pLvjmue4/1/

**HTML**

```
<a>a1</a><a>a1</a><a>a1</a>
<p>p1</p><p>p1</p><p>p1</p>
<span>s1</span><span>s1</span><span>s1</span>
<div>d1</div><div>d1</div><div>d1</div>
<br>
<input/>
<input/>
<input/>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
}
a{
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
}
p{
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: blue;
}
span{
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: green;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black
}
img{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
input{  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

White space is added to inline-block elements, see the following example of this in inspector:

[image: Inspector]

A work around would be to place them like the following in your HTML:

```html
<div>
  <input /><input /><input />
</div>
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 0;">
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
</div>
<div>
  <input />
  <input />
  <input />
</div>
```

You can also use `display: flex` as well.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w548tLfy/

Comment: Thanks,  I see the return character in the actual HTML was causing this.  The mods required that I re-state my question.  In general input behave differently.  The most obvious is the default width of 145px.  Where does this come from?  It is not in the browser user-agent or the CSS I provided

Comment: Inline (and inline-block) elements respect whitespace in the markup, this is the space character between words in the HTML markup.